# How to change the position of the div after file upload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to reposition my browse button when the user uploaded a file. This is the sample of how it should really look before and after uploading the file:

Before:

[image: Before uploading]

After:

[image: After uploading]

I change the content of my button "Browse file" to "Replace File"

This is my html code.

```
<div id="uploadModal" class="upload-modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <h2 style="font-size: 24px;">Choose file</h2>
            <p>
              Choose the csv file containing the data you want to create a forecast for.
            </p>
            <div class="browse-file">
              <div id="filename"></div>
              <input type="file" id="file-upload" multiple required />
              <label for="file-upload">Browse file</label>
            </div>
            <div class="options">
              <button class="cancel"><h4>Cancel</h4></button>
              <button class="proceed"><h4>Proceed</h4></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.upload-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 34, 2, 0.3);
}
input[type="file"] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  
}
input + label {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  background: #D4E8CF;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: static;
  width: 119px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
#filename{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

What's happening here is that my button moves according to the length of the file so I added max-width but no luck. Thanks!

EDIT: I added css for upload-modal

Comment: can you provide css for upload-model?

Comment: If you want to always have it on the right edge of the containing div you could try using `float:right`  in the element style after the file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to use absolute positioning for what you want.

You could set div#upload-modal or div.modal-content to position: relative;

and then position the button element with left: or right: or use float: right;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

This alternate version uses CSS's [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and JavaScript's [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

It probably doesn't do precisely what you want but should come close enough that reading through the comments a few times and playing around with the code should make clear how you can get to where you want to go using just a few lines of JavaScript to grab the file name and show it on the screen.

MDN (linked above) is a great place to get more clarity about any particular front-end feature that you're interested in using. Happy coding!

```js
// Unnamed function runs as soon as the DOM elements are ready
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Identifies some of the DOM elements
  const
    filenameSpan = document.getElementById("filename-span"),
    fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input"),
    chooseBtn = document.getElementById("choose-btn");

  // When the input changes (when a file is chosen), calls `updateDisplay`
  fileInput.addEventListener("change", updateDisplay);

  // Defines `updateDisplay`
  function updateDisplay(){

    // Puts first fiename in span and "unhides" it
    const filename = fileInput.files[0]?.name;
    filenameSpan.textContent = filename || "(choose file)";
    filenameSpan.classList.remove("hidden");
  };
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}
#container{
  width: 18rem; /* "rem" unit is the base character height */
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#header{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
#chooser{
  /* flex w/ space-around makes choose-btn shift right when filename appears */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
#options{
  text-align: right;
}

#filename-span{
  padding: 1rem 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 6rem;
}
button{ /* the "options" buttons */
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgreen;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#choose-btn{
  /* Not a true "button" element -- the "label" for file-input */
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.hidden{ /* Uses a class so all styling happens thru CSS */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
        <h2>Choose file</h2>
        <p> Choose the csv file containing the data you want to create a forecast for</p>
    </div>

    <div id="chooser">
        <!-- The span and input elements are initially "hidden" via CSS -->
        <span id="filename-span" class="hidden"></span>
        <label id="choose-btn">
            <!-- input element is inside its stylable & clickable label -->
            Browse File
            <input id="file-input" type="file" class="hidden" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <div id="options">
        <button id="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        <button id="proceed-btn">Proceed</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: works fine, thanks!